# Unable to install nodes in node-red

Tags: npm, node-red

[image]

please help in installing node-red dashboard to my node-red
I tried fixing all npm issues, but could'nt fix this.

Comment: Please do not post images of error messages, post the actual text and then format it. As it is that image is very hard to read and impossible for people using screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

The error says the machine where the Node-RED backend is running is having DNS problems and can not resolve npmjs.org

This is unlikely to be something we can help you fix, you need to work out why that machine is having DNS issues.

p.s. Also `cn-dashboard-nodes` is not the Node-RED Dashboard, you probably want to be installing `node-red-dashboard`